# How to load an image using Phaser

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I'm trying to learn how to use Phaser, following instructions online on how to load an image; one of the examples that phaser offers is the load images example.

Here is the code that Phaser offers.

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create });

function preload() {

    //  You can fill the preloader with as many assets as your game requires

    //  Here we are loading an image. The first parameter is the unique
    //  string by which we'll identify the image later in our code.

    //  The second parameter is the URL of the image (relative)
    game.load.image('einstein', 'assets/pics/ra_einstein.png');

}

function create() {

    //  This creates a simple sprite that is using our loaded image and
    //  displays it on-screen
    game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'einstein');

}
```

html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Experiments</title>
  <script src="../phaser.js"></script>
  <script src="game.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to run this code on my server (using node) but I don't see the image, can somebody explain me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to add `<div id="phaser-example"></div>` inside `<body></body>` tag

```
<html>
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Experiments</title>
       <script src="../phaser.js"></script>
       <script src="game.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div id="phaser-example"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

js:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create });

function preload() {

    //  You can fill the preloader with as many assets as your game requires

    //  Here we are loading an image. The first parameter is the unique
    //  string by which we'll identify the image later in our code.

    //  The second parameter is the URL of the image (relative)
    game.load.image('einstein', 'assets/pics/ra_einstein.png');

}

function create() {

    //  This creates a simple sprite that is using our loaded image and
    //  displays it on-screen
    game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'einstein');

}
```